# Make money based on interest rate cut in Canada

Tags: canada, interest-rate

Bank of Canada recently announced reduction in its prime rate. As a Canadian, is there a way to take advantage of it? For example, if I bet that in the next 12 months, the rate would increase, how can  I make money on this bet?

Comment: Short sell long term bonds?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - I was going to suggest buying puts on the long bond.

Comment: Another option is to buy non-Canadian currency you think will do better

Comment: @JL a rising rate can attract foreign money and actually cause the Looney to rise, not fall.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Can you elaborate please? What do you mean by long bond?Is there a bond etf for this (like XBB)?

Comment: @Victor123 - I can't. I am USian. And I know we have derivatives on everything. So I was considering this trade for my gambling money.  I've not researched it for Canada.

Comment: @Victor123 I wouldn't bet on it.  We live in strange times.  ZFS.TO is a short bond ETF but these are super risky, if you get the timing wrong you can lose money even if the rates do go up.  Consider investing in energy companies or mining companies as some sort of proxy for the health of the global and local economies.  If oil price goes up, e.g., they'll do better and we could expect rates would also go up.